# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' React nginx error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, nginx, webserver

I am trying to run nginx on a virtual machine server that i have purchased to run my website that i am creating. I am fairly new to webservers and setting them up in general but i seem to have got the nginx config to at least direct to the proper index file. But for some reason i am getting the error above. I think its because its expecting js and getting html or vice versa. Below is all my code:

Index.html in ./EqualityTee/front-end/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Trend.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script  src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js in ./EqualityTee/front-end/src/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Auth0Provider } from "./react-auth0-spa.js";
import config from "./utils/auth_config.json";
import history from "./utils/history.js";

// A function that routes the user to the right place
// after login
const onRedirectCallback = appState => {
  history.push(
    appState && appState.targetUrl
      ? appState.targetUrl
      : window.location.pathname
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Auth0Provider
    domain={config.domain}
    client_id={config.clientId}
    redirect_uri={window.location.origin}
    onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
  >
    <App />
  </Auth0Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

nginx config file

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/EqualityTee;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index /front-end/public/index.html;

        server_name equalityfits.com www.equalityfits.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri /front-end/public/index.html$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ .(static)/(js|css|media)/(.+)$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3;
        }
```

Access Log

```
38.103.205.179 - - [24/Jun/2020:17:25:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36"
```

No errors in error log

When i run a local server using my website the bundle.js is pointed at the location https://localhost:8080/bundle.js so i think i have it pointing to the right location, but what am i missing here?